# Filtering out the rows in certain condition

Tags: python, awk

I am trying to filter out the rows that has certain value that matches the value from other file. I'd appreciate for a help.

My data looks like this:

File1:

```
  Group   Position Code     Answer  c1     c2    c3    c4   
  1       3        s1_60    A       etc    etc   etc   etc
  2       4        s2_63    T       etc2_  etc2  etc2/ etc2'
  3       5        s1_23    A       etc3   etc3  etc3* etc3
  3       51       s7_52    T       etc4   etc4_ etc4  etc4^
```

File2:

```
>1
ATGCGCGCGCGCGATATATTGCTGATATATATGCCTTttaagatcaatat
tattagccccatgtgttgaagaacaaatctctctgttaaacagaaattgg
gggggaaaataaacaggggggcaaataattctgactacaattgtatatat
ggatatattGCGCGCGCGCGAGAGAGAGAGAtgtgttgtagataGACGAG
>2
tattagccccatgtgttgaagaacaaatctctctgttaaacagaaattgg
gggggaaaataaacaggggggcaaataattctgactacaattgtatatat
ggatatattGCGCGCaaaaaaGAGAGAGAGAGAtgtgttgtagataGACG
>3
tattagccccatgtgttgaagaacaaatctctctgttaaacagaaattgg
gggggaaaataaacaggggggcaaataattctgactacaattgtatatat
ggatatattGCGCGCGCGccggcgcgcgAGAtgtgttgtagataGACGAG
```

'Group' refers to the number after '>' on 'File2' while 'Position' refers to the position of the letter under the designated group. I want to keep only the rows that have the matching letter from 'File2' in 'Answer' column.

Therefore, output would look like this:

newOutput:

```
Group   Position  Code      Answer  c1     c2    c3    c4
  2       4        s2_63    T       etc2_  etc2  etc2/ etc2'
  3       5        s1_23    A       etc3   etc3  etc3* etc3
  3       51       s7_52    T       etc4   etc4_ etc4  etc4^
```

First line on 'File1' was not included because it has 'A' instead of 'K'

I would appreciate for any help. I am thinking about starting with either awk or python. I have never organized data with multiple files involved so it is kind of frustrating for me. Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open("File2") as infile:
    d = {}
    bases = ''
    group = None
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith(">"):
            if group is not None:
                d[group] = bases
            group = int(line[1:])
            bases = ''
            continue
        bases += line
    d[group] = bases.upper()

with open("File1") as infile, open('output', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(next(reader))
    for g, pos, code, answer, *rest in reader:
        g = int(g)
        pos = int(pos)
        if d[g][pos-1] == ans:
            writer.writerow([g, pos, code, answer] + rest)
```

Comment: it says:
    d[group] = line.strip()
NameError: name 'line' is not defined Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3557715: oops! Sorry about that. It's fixed now

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed it too. I have another problem though. on "group = int(group[1:].strip())" I think its striping the lines that do not start with > as well. its showing something like "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ALKFEKSSGESDGASHSDG'" Is there any way I can apply that only toward the ones that start with '>'?

Comment: @user3557715: I just tested the posted code against your sample and it worked. I have a feeling that somewhere in File2, you have an empty line or a group with multiple lines. Please verify this, and post a representative sample of File2 in your OP so that I know what we're dealing with

Comment: Im really sorry for the confusion. Yes, File2 has multiple lines under the groupname. I made more accurate example on OP. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3557715: I've changed it. It doesn't give what you ask for your OP, but I verified the results manually

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems to work but I have another problem. I should have given you more detailed example because I had many other columns consisting of letters or numbers. I think because of that reason it is showing this error probably because contents are not all integers. "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S1_60'" I changed the example to reflect some other columns. Sorry for the mess. How can i fix this?

Comment: @user3557715: I don't see anything along the lines of `S1_60` in your example. I don't know what you mean

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion. There is an additional 3rd column consisting of letter, underscore, and numbers. There are also various other columns after "answer" column consisting of letter,numbers,special character. I am sorry this is a big time fail and a mess. Can you help me from here?

Comment: What is the logic that produces `T` from `2 4 s2_63`?

Comment: Only column 1,2,4 (group,position,answer) are related. All other various columns are just there and would not involve in any calculation or logic but I still want them to carry on as a row to the final product. Those various columns all have different combination of letter number and special characters. I think that is making an error on the script.. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @user3557715: that should do it (on python3). Check it out and let me know

Comment: Hi This seems to work. I sent you an email to your gmail listed on your website. Please check your email! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk solution:

```
BEGIN {
    GROUP=1;
    BASE=2;
}
NR == FNR {
    positions[$1"_"$2]=toupper($3)
}

NR != FNR {
    if($0 ~ /^>/) {
        group=substr($0, 2, length($0));
    } else {
        gsub(" ", "", $0);
        seqs[group]=seqs[group]$0;
    }
}

END {
    print "Group","Position","Answer"
    for(current_group in seqs) {
        for(key in positions) {
            split(key,position,"_");
            if(position[GROUP] == current_group) {
                if(toupper(substr(seqs[group],position[BASE],1)) \
                        == positions[key]) {
                    print position[GROUP],
                          position[BASE],
                          positions[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`awk -f script.awk File1 File2`

output:

```
Group Position Answer
2 4 T
3 5 A
```

Position 51 of group 3 appears to be a `G`, not a `T`, so my output is different from yours.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I have extra columns as you can see from edited OP. What should I change to reflect those extra columns?

Comment: you can make a few superficial edits to the code I have provided to accomplish that, namely storing the extra columns in the `positions` associative array and then reading them back out again, changing your question that much is a little unfair to me though :)